# How to read a specific block size of a file C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How is it possible to read a specific block size of a file?

I am trying to write a file to a tape-drive, and because its blocksize is 32768 I need to make sure that the file handle is set to 3278 as well

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Read a block from a file? Or determine the block size?

Comment: basically you can open the stream and seek to a specific position then read a specific amount of bytes from there, you don't necessarily need to read from position 0. see here for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975410/fastest-way-in-c-sharp-to-read-block-of-bytes-from-file-and-converting-to-float

Comment: Some context would be nice, maybe post some code, or explain what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: -1: What do you mean by "block", I can - without trying - think of several potential meanings for "block", which allows me to interpret your question in several different ways. Can you disambugate the question please?

Comment: @alex I have updated by question

Comment: @Codo I am trying to write data to a tape drive, but I need to make sure the file handler uses the same block size as the tape

Answer (score 0):

I've read your earlier question about it. It seems that you're opening the tape drive with [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (using Interop) and some special flags. Are you sure these flags are really needed? Try it without them? It might be that your tape drive can handle read and write operation of any size.

If not, then use [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (again with the help of Interop) to access the tape. Then you have full control and can nicely align your I/O operations with device blocks.